# Button "New Item" in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page that works with various models.

One of the items is "Language", where I select the language and level. But I can only insert a single language. I wonder what the best way to insert a "New" button to add another language, even if the edit page (because even though I need to include in the edit page too)

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for and simple_form.

Have tried several solutions but could not find any similar tutorial with what I need.

Comment: Is language is separate `model` or just an `attribute`?

Comment: Pavan, language is a separate model.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention you have a page which `works with various models`, you need to remember `views != models`. In rails, views are used to show data you have defined in your `controllers`.

When you ask about inserting a `new` button to add a new language, this will be entirely dependent on your interface, and how you wish it to work. A good example would be this:

```
#app/views/languages/_new_lang.html.erb
<%= form_for Language.new, url: language_path do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

A better way to do this will be to use ajax & render a layout-less element on your page:

```
#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= button_to "Test", new_language_path, remote: true, id: "test" %>

#app/controllers/languages_controller.rb
Class LanaguageController < ActiveRecord::Base
    layout Proc.new { |controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#test", function(data) {
    $(data).appendTo("body");
});
```

This will allow you to send the required data through to your system to create a new language. Can be improved, so if you want to use it please let me know in the comments

Comment: Thank you Rich! 

I'll try. If it works I post here.